TeachingTip pointer placement is placed a bit on the right side of the target when app is launched
I am working on a WinUI app. I have noticed the TeachingTip pointer placement is not correct when it is opened for the first time after the app is launched. But when i opened it second time the pointer placement is correct. I have attached the images and added the code snippets below for reference. How to fix this ?


<controls:TeachingTip x:Name="TeachingTip1" Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.TeachingTipContent}" CornerRadius="10" Target={x:Bind MainButton/>

<Button x:Name="MainButton" Command="{x:Bind ViewModel.MainButtonCommand}"/>


Can you share the code around how you implemented this?

<controls: TeachingTip x:Name="TeachingTip_Customer" Content="{x:Bind ViewModel.TeachingTipView}" PreferredPlacement="Bottom" Target={x:Bind CustomerButton" />
This is the code I have used , the target is a button here.

It might help including the target control which seems to be a TavView. Since someone closed this, you need to request a reopen.
